# Sharing Data between Smart Devices without wifi

Tags: android, networking

I have heard of communication between two android devices using that touch method or however that works.  I understand that communication over WiFi is not a problem.  I need to know if it is possible to create an app that would run on multiple devices but in the end would compile data collected on each device into one main database all done without WiFi.  It just sounds like a hogwash idea in my mind but is this possible?

Comment: And where will this main database be held? I assume a server which would mean the device would be connected to the internet most likely via WIFI. If you mean communicating between multiple devices without WIFI there are a few means. Bluetooth is one of them as well as high frequency sounds. The Google Play Services API has the ability to do such things. All of these ways require the users to be close in range.

Comment: @chRyNaN Have you done any work with communicating multiple (3+) devices via bluetooth/high frequency sounds?  That is more the direction I had planned on heading towards.

Comment: I have not personally but have a look at their resources on the subjects: https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview .

Comment: Thanks will take a look into it!

Answer (score 0):

There is app call SuperBeam.You'll need SuperBeam installed on both devices and then you'll need to pair the devices using any of a number of methods, including QR Codes, NFC, or by typing a manual code.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGAAE7qru6g 
youtube link if you want to see how to use SuperBeam app
Correction:I tought this app don't use wifi but i guess this app for devices aren't connect to the same Wifi